# Upload file page in Wordpress and reponse there

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I'm a beginner in PHP but an expert in programming in general, so I program C and C++ usually, but I have no experience with posting and getting with PHP, so I don't really understand the exact mechanism how this works.

Yesterday I worked for like two hours on my webserver and set a page on my Wordpress to make visitors upload a file. The page submits a form to a custom PHP page, but that page is empty and dull, and I would like to make the confirmation page in Wordpress itself. What I tried to do for that is that I created a new page, and used the plugin "insert PHP", and simply pasted the code from the page, to which the form submits, and made my upload form post to that Wordpress page. This doesn't seem to work.

How can I get this to work?
Simplifying the question: How can I make my form in wordpress post to another wordpress page and give the response in a wordpress page rather than a PHP page created from scratch?

If my question is not clear or requires any additional information to be answered, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to get to know [specialized page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Specialized_Page_Template) in WordPress, and the page templating system in general. Ideally, you'd create a page in wp-admin and create a specialized page template for it.

If you're doing form processing, you can do that in the new template...but may be better off moving that logic to the **functions.php** file. Use [action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to ensure that your processing functions are run on submit.

Comment: No. I'm sorry. I used a plugin called "insert_php", and wrote my own php script and included it in my page. That worked find by posting the form to the same page by making action="".